# Building Spring XD locally

Tags: spring-xd

I am testing XD locally. I am using eclipse. For each code change, I am using gradlew copyInstall task to build XD and test it. It takes upto 15 mins to build. As I keep making changes, anyway I can reflect latest code changes in XD distribution (like copying a JAR or making eclipse copy the class files). Any less tome consuming way to test incremental changes will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./gradlew copyInstall -xtest -xjavadoc -xsetupui will speed things up significantly